# opencv errors while using with windows form applications

Tags: c++, visual-studio, opencv

I am using opencv with visual studio 2010 windows form application c++. but it wont allow calling inbuilt functions. It gives errors like

Error   1   error C3861: 'cvCvtColor': identifier not found c:\users\ayesha\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\abc\abc\Form1.h   140 1   abc

Error   2   error C3861: 'cvCvtPixToPlane': identifier not found    c:\users\ayesha\documents\visual studio 2010\projects\abc\abc\Form1.h   146 1   abc

I have added the following headers

```
#include "highgui.h"
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp" 
#include "opencv2/core/core.hpp"      
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui.hpp"
```

Can anyone please tell me what i am doing wrong.

Comment: which OpenCV version do you use, maybe it's really not a member of your version.

Comment: When posting a question about compiler errors, please include the *complete* and *unedited* error log. Please edit your question to include that.

Answer (score 3):

Unfortunately, OP doesn't say what version of OpenCV he uses.

While working with OpenCV 3.0, use `cvSplit()` instead of `cvCvtPixToPlane()`.

`cvCvtColor()` shall work with OpenCV 3.0, provided you added the required header files to your projects.

Finally, to make sure you don't miss any required files in your project, just start your code with `#include <opencv2\opencv.hpp>`.

Answer (score 0):

`cvCvtColor` is a C API function of OpenCV, but you're intending to use the C++ one. You have 2 ways of fixing the problem:

1) (Recommended) Change your source code to use the C++ API. You should use `cv::Mat` instead of `CvArr`, `cv::cvtColor` instead of `cvCvtColor`, etc.

2) Since such changes in the source code can be pretty involved, you can still use the C API by including C-headers

```
#include "opencv2/imgproc/imgproc_c.h" 
#include "opencv2/core/core_c.h"      
#include "opencv2/highgui/highgui_c.h"
```

instead of the C++ (*.hpp) ones

Comment: ans in case of second it didn't identify header

Comment: For me, this one solved the problem`#include <opencv2/imgproc/imgproc.hpp>`

Answer (score 0):

The error you've mentioned it is a linker error I suppose. 
As you're including two headers highgui.hpp and highgui.h targeting to an identical library which is opencv_highgui23#.
Just include only one header.

Comment: Have you added the OpenCV libraries in your project configurations ?